# Write function in laravel which needs to execute before any controller

Tags: laravel-4

Hi i am doing a website in laravel.
I am trying to do like a function that needs to execute before any controller.

**Example :**
I have function like

```
function xyz(){
    //do code here
}
```

This function need to execute when user on site by refreshing page or doing some ajax requst.

I am aware with the codeigniter there is a way to do this using hook

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'MyClass',
        'function' => 'Myfunction',
        'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks',
        'params'   => array('beer', 'wine', 'snacks')
);
```

What is the way in laravel to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Laravel Middleware to achieve this. The middleware can be registered as global for all controllers / routes, and will let you execute that function (or you can register it for subset of routes by using router groups).

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class MyMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // call your function
        $this->xyz();

        return $next($request);
    }

    public function xyz()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

See the [Laravel documentation on Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware).

Comment: can we use Filter of laravel to do this.

Comment: Route filters have been deprecated in preference of middleware and were removed entirely with the release of Laravel 5.2 in December 2015.

Comment: @My laravel project version is 4.2

Comment: The why did you tag this as Laravel 5? In Laravel 4.2, you will have to use Filter.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to declare the function in the public construct part of your controller. For example, if you had a Controller for all pages as follows and you need to check if a user is above a certain age.

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    
   public function __construct()
    {
     Run this function for every function in controller
     $this->middleware('age');
        
     }
 public function index()
 {
   //my public static page
 }
}
```

Create a middleware with the artisan command

```
 php artisan make:middleware AgeMiddleware
```

in your AgeMiddleware, you can have a function as follows.

```
class AgeMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Run the request filter.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->input('age') <= 200) {
           //Do whatever you want, in this case I redirect home
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```